# Linux command line tools to create videos from text

Tags: linux, video, command-line

Which Linux command line tool(s) can be used to create videos from text?
ffmpeg can be used to make videos from images but can it be used to make videos only from text?
I have used ffmpeg for cutting or cropping the videos, don't know much about it but this is the only tool I know. Is it versatile to make videos from text with some animation etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ffmpeg` to create "black" video, like this ([source](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-October/002602.html)):

```
ffmpeg -t 60 -s qcif -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 25 -i /dev/zero silence.mpeg
```

and then add text as subtitles ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672809/use-ffmpeg-to-add-text-subtitles))

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -i infile.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text outfile.mp4
```